# How to create Docker Container for Mongodb with data which should be deployed to azure cluster

Tags: azure, docker

Can anyone know how to create a docker container for the mongo db database files copied. I do see use dump and restore mechanism which would not be helpful if I need to deploy container to azure cluster. In my case Mongodb database is getting changed very frequently.

Here is my current docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

ENV MONGO_VERSION 3.4.19

COPY mongo.msi mongo.msi
COPY MongoData/db C:\\data\\db

RUN Write-Host 'Installing ...'; \

Start-Process msiexec -Wait \
    -ArgumentList @( \
        '/i', \
        'mongo.msi', \
        '/quiet', \
        '/qn', \
        'INSTALLLOCATION=C:\mongodb', \
        'ADDLOCAL=all' \
    ); \
$env:PATH = 'C:\mongodb\bin;' + $env:PATH; \
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); \
\
Write-Host 'Verifying install ...'; \
Write-Host '  mongo --version'; mongo --version; \
Write-Host '  mongod --version'; mongod --version; \
\
Write-Host 'Removing ...'; \
Remove-Item C:\mongodb\bin\*.pdb -Force; \
Remove-Item C:\windows\installer\*.msi -Force; \
Remove-Item mongo.msi -Force; \
\
Write-Host 'Complete.';


EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod", "--bind_ip_all"]
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Buddha

Comment: Maybe you can persist the volume which the database files in while the mongo db change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Charles-xu. I could not understand your suggestion. Can you please elaborate it. I just added current docker file content for better understanding.

Comment: I don't use the database, but if you stored the sql files in a persist volume that without changing so that your database will not change. Is that right?

Comment: Yes I agree. But I am looking for changed database files to be moved to azure cluster.

Comment: Well, but if you use the Windows system and want to run it as Docker in Azure, then the persist volume is not available now. Also, AKS cluster is not available for windows nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response @Charles Xu. I found the solution for this. What we should do is:

1. Create a docker container
2. With Mongo service, dump the database which extracts bson and json files from mongodb files). Run the **mongodump --host "localhost:27017"** command in powershell with admin mode
3. Restore the extracted data to container. Run the command **mongorestore --host
   localhost:27030** (docker container running with this port).
4. Commit the docker changes, which push the data changes done in step 3 to docker image.
5. Publish/push the docker image to azure which will have data persisted

Hope this helps somebody.